# Relating Turning Angle To Arc

Tags: circles, kinematics

I am trying to determine how to relate the turning angle of a vehicle to an arc. For the purposes of this vehicle, I am not taking into account [Ackerman Steering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_steering_geometry), so for the intent of this question, the vehicle is essentially just one-wheeled (like a bike)

I need to know how to calculate the angle, in relation to the body of the vehicle, that the front axle needs to turn in order for the front of the car to go from point `a` to point `b` in a scenario such as
illustrated below.

[image]

This is all assuming I know:

1. The arc length
2. The chord length
3. The radius of the circle

How do I determine this steering angle?

Comment: I think the diagram isn't quite right ant the back wheel should also be on the circle, so the back wheel follows the same path as the front wheel. In which case, each axle points towsrds the centre of the circle and the single depends on the vehicle length and the circle radius.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The rear axle is fixed--it won't turn. Only the front axle turns, so  the way I drew the diagram was the way I meant it.

Comment: The whole vehicle turns, though. Put the front axle at an angle to the back one, and each axle points towsrds the centre of the turning circle. That's what I mean. (Treating it as one wheel behind the other, like a bivycle)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at...the way this vehicle works, the vehicle will start the way it's positioned in the diagram, except that the front axle will be angled. What I don't know is how to calculate the angle of the front axle.

Comment: @timtfj In reality, unless the vehicle is on rails, every wheel follows a different path.

Comment: OK I get what you mean. In that case, the angle obviously has to change as the vehicle moves forward—if it's *initially* at an angle, it immediately moves off the circle. So it becomes a question of how the angle changes as the vehicle moves forwards.

Comment: No...sorry I'm not being clear @timtfj I want to know what angle the front wheels need to be at initially so that they don't have to change while they follow the arc of the circle. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense—but I'm saying that it's a contradictory requirement unless the wheels are allowed to skid. For the front wheel to roll along the circle, its axle must be perpendicular to the tangent at that point, so its direction is determined by the distance travelled. The rear wheel will roll perpendicularly to its (fixed) axle, thereby determining the motion of the rear of the vehicle, so the actual angle between the two axles depends on the instantaneous position of the vehicle, which changes.

Comment: If the two axles are at a fixed angle (assuming one wheel per axle as in the question), the vehicle will move along a circle whose centre is given by the intersection of the lines through the two axles, which is a different circle from the one you want.

Comment: Okay, so to summarize, there is a vehicle centered on a particular path whose curvature is constant (by whatever measure of curvature you want to use). And given the arc length, chord length, and radius of the curve, you want to know the angle that the line perpendicular to the front axle makes with the line tangent to the circle at the car's location; pretending for the time being that the entire axle turns to face the direction the car is steering in so as to avoid Ackerman steering. Did I get all that right?

Comment: @R.Burton that's exactly what I mean. timtfj I see what you mean...I sorry this is so confusing. I want the front to end up at point b, if that helps. I will edit the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question you need to know two things:

1) The radius $r$ of the curve

2) The distance $l$ from a point on the curve (which I will assume is the center of the car) to the center of the front axle.

Since a circle has constant curvature, the angle will be the same no matter which two points on the circle you pick.

---

(Formula provided at end, you can skip the derivation if you want)

---

Now, there's a slight mechanical problem here: the car has minimum turning radius, and without having a lot more information (friction, weight distribution, drivetrain specs, etc.) it isn't really possible to say what that minimum is. So, for the sake of argument, let's just say that the center of the car is affixed to the circle by a rail, the car is front wheel drive, and the rear wheels have no friction.

This means that, at most, $l$ is twice $r$, and the front axle is always perpendicular to the direction the car is facing (i.e. the car is spinning in a circle without moving forward). If you treat the rear wheels as the fixed point instead of the center of the car, then you can redefine $l$ as the distance between the center of the rear axle and that of the front axle - the maximum value of $l$ remains the same.

Now you have the first value of a function which outputs the desired angle given the ratio between $r$ and $l$, namely $(r,2r)\mapsto \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Now consider the other extreme - suppose that $r$ is infinitely greater than $l$. A circle whose radius is infinite is the same as a straight line, so the angle of the front axle would be zero. This gives a second value for your function: $(r,0r)\mapsto 0$ ($l=0r$ because $r$ is infinite).

Thus, we can conclude that the angle, is directly proportional to $l$ and inversely proportional to $r$. $\quad\left(\theta\propto\frac{l}{r}\right)$. If $x=\frac{l}{r}$, then you are looking for a function $f(x)=\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle you want. Furthermore, you know that $f(0)=0$ and $f(2)=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Since the input to your function is a ratio between two lengths and the output is an angle, we are likely dealing with an inverse trigonometric function.

(This is the part where you start drawing things, if you haven't already)

---

There are several ways to obtain the correct function using different trig identities, but all are equivalent to:

$$\theta=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{l}{2r}\right)$$

---

Note: I can provide a more formal geometric derivation, if you'd like

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much! I would never have derived that on my own.